# data not passed from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to do some basic data sending from view to controller in **codeigniter**. But it is not sending for some reason. I am using jquery ajax method to send data.

Here is my **view file :**

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    // e.preventDefault();
    str = $('#form1').serialize();
    name =  $("#name").val();
    alert(name);
    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo site_url('home/file_upload'); ?>',
        method : 'POST',
        data : { 'name' : name },
        //contentType: 'application/json',

        //dataType : "json",
        success : function()
        {
            location.href =  '<?php echo site_url('home/file_upload'); ?>';
        },
        error : function()
        {
            alert("failed");
        }

    });
})
```

and my **controller code :**

```
public function file_upload()
{
    // $name = $_POST['name'];
    // print_r($name);
    $name =  $this->input->post('name');
    print_r($name);


    //$this->load->view('file_upload', '$data');
}
```

It shows a blank page. If I use print_r($_POST) in controller, it displays blank array i.e. array( ))

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: inside sucess you are redirecting to the samw page and at that time nothing has been passed as post that is why u got empty page.  you have monitor ajax request in firebug console window where you can view the result

Comment: Thanks. that helped to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
public function file_upload(){
  if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST'){

    $name =  $this->input->post('name');
    print_r($name);
  }else{
    redirect(base_url());
  }
}
```